# combination and permutation of data frame columns

Tags: r, algorithm, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I would need some help to compute all the combination and permutation  of data frame column.
My `df` looks like this (the real one has 40+ columns and 15000+ rows)

```
ID      A   B   C   D
ID_1    NA  1   NA  1
ID_2    1   1   1   1
ID_3    1   1   1   1
ID_4    NA  1   1   NA
ID_5    1   1   1   1
ID_6    1   NA  NA  1
ID_7    1   1   1   1
ID_8    1   NA  NA  NA
ID_9    1   1   1   1
ID_10   1   1   1   1
ID_11   1   1   1   1
ID_12   NA  NA  1   1
ID_13   NA  NA  1   NA
ID_14   1   1   1   NA
```

Where the first column contains an unique ID, and column 2:40+ contain either 1 (present) or NA (absent).

Now I would need to know how many IDs are 'present' for each combination and permutation
AB, AC, AD, BC.....ABC, ABD.....ABCDE, ABCDF.... and so on.

Using `combinat` I can easily retrieve all the possible combinations/permutation (assuming a 4 columns data frame) by

```
for (i in 1:3){
  combn(4, i)
next}
```

But then, how can I use this to calculate what I need and get the results in a data frame like

```
1   2   3   4
A   AB  ABC ABCD
B   AC  ABD na
C   AD  ACD na
D   BC  BCD na
na  BD  na  na
na  CD  na  na
```

Comment: You are asking for >= 2^40 counts, which is not feasible, I guess. I guess most of those combos will have zero count, anyways, so maybe you can do without explicitly enumerating them.

Comment: Also does `ID_1` count as `B`, `D`, `BD`, and `DB`?

Comment: Are you sure you want all the combinations AND permutations? Looks to me like all you need is combinations.

Comment: Maybe permutations is not the right word, but I want all the combination from n=1 to n=40, I.e. A, AB, ABC, ABCD, ABCDE....B, BC, BCD, BCDE... the true permutations AB BA are not relevant, as they would give the same result

Comment: what do you plan to do with the results..?

Comment: No other calculation. I need to report the table (i.e. how many IDs you get when using 1,2,3,4...., or 40 columns). Maybe plotting them as a whole or part of it somehow (bar plot or box plots... Will have to try and see what looks "better')

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a way to solve this, but it is super slow (>12h on a data set of 20 columns and 18000 rows), so any suggestion for improvements are welcome.

Assuming an initial data table where the column "ID" has been removed, and looks like this

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   NA
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   NA  NA  NA
1   1   NA  1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   NA
NA  1   1   NA  1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   NA  1
NA  1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   NA  1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   NA  NA  1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   NA  1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   NA
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
NA  1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   NA  1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   NA  NA  1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   NA  1
1   1   1   1   NA  1   NA  1
1   1   NA  1   1   1   NA  1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   NA
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   NA
1   1   1   NA  1   1   1   NA
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1
```

I first compute all the possible combination using `combn` in this way

```
combi <- as.data.frame(t(colnames(dt)))

for (i in 2:ncol(dt)){
  combi <- cbind.fill(combi, as.data.frame(combn(colnames(dt), i)),  fill = NA)
next}
```

Then I create a table for the final result

```
final <- data.frame(group = apply(combi, 2 , function(x) length(which(x != "" ))) , value = c(NA))
```

Last, I calculate the number of IDs present in each combination

```
for (i in 1:ncol(combi)){
  final[i, 2] <- nrow(dt[ , c(which(colnames(dt) %in% c(as.character(na.omit(combi[, i]))))), with = FALSE][!apply(dt[ , c(which(colnames(dt) %in% c(as.character(na.omit(combi[, i]))))), with = FALSE] == "", 1, all),])
next}
```

To get the final results I want I just do this

```
result <- subset(final, group == 1)[,2]
for (i in 2:max(final[, 1])){
  result <- cbind.fill(result, subset(final, group == i)[,2],  fill = NA)
next}
```

The generation of the combinations table `combi` and the calculation on `final` are the bottle neck, it works fine for small data, but as I said it is incredibly slow on big data set even on a kick-ass machine.